# How to solve System.IO.FileNotFoundException for Cefsharp

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-assembly, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am building a web scraping app using Cefsharp.Offscreen. I use Visual Studio 22 and net framework 6 or 7. I have installed Cefsharp.Offscreen, Cefsharp.WinForms, Cefsharp.Common, cef.redist.x64 and cef.redist.x86 as dependencies.

I have this code:

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
namespace cefsharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        private void InitializeChromium()
        {
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser.LoadUrl("https://google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application in x64 debug mode. It gives error in `InitializeChromium()` method. Full description of the error is "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=112.2.70.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'. The system cannot find the file specified'

I checked /bin folder and coudn't see the "cefsharp.dll" file and some other dlls. I guess, it is because of it. But I don't know how to add them.

Note: I have NU1701 warning in error list.

Also, when I try to change the `browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();` line with  `browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");` It gives CS0012 error descripted as "Htmlstring defined in an assembly that is not refferenced" I tried to edit app.config file but, coudnt fix.

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Check the FAQ at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#4-why-do-i-get-an-error-about-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharpcoredll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-when-trying-to-run-my-cefsharp-based-application-it-compiles-successfully-but-does-not-run-it-runs-on-my-developer-machine-though-throws-an-exception-when-i-copy-it-to-another-computer

Comment: You need to use the `NETCore` nuget packages. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start-For-MS-.Net-5.0-or-greater

Answer (score 0):

> I use Visual Studio 22 and net framework 6 or 7. I have installed Cefsharp.Offscreen, Cefsharp.WinForms, Cefsharp.Common, cef.redist.x64 and cef.redist.x86 as dependencies.

For `.Net Core 3.1/.Net 5/6/7+` you need to use the `NETCore` NuGet packages. The packages you are attempting to use only support `.Net 4.x`.

Install one of the following via the `Nuget Package Manager` from within Visual Studio

- [image: CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore]
- [image: CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore]
- [image: CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore]

See also [Quick Start For MS .Net 5.0 or greater](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start-For-MS-.Net-5.0-or-greater)